# Are there any references to Firefly in Halo 3: ODST?

Tags: halo-3-odst

As far as I know, Nathan Fillion squeezes in any references he can to Firefly in any role he plays, in any movie, TV show, or cameo.

[image: Castle Halloween]

[image: Percy Jackson 2]

However, I can't remember whether or not he managed to get one into ODST. Are there any, or did he miss the chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All information sourced from the [list of pop culture references at the Halo wikia](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_pop_culture_references_in_Halo).**

There are actually three actors that featured in both Firefly and the Halo series: [Adam Baldwin](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Adam_Baldwin), [Nathan Fillion](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Nathan_Fillion) and [Alan Tudyk](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Alan_Tudyk). These three voice actors are reported to voice all Firefly references, in game.

- Marines voiced by Adam Baldwin will randomly say "Say 'hi' to Vera!" and "Gee, it'd be nice if we brought some grenades, wouldn't it?". The second quote is a direct quote from the character Jayne Cobb of Firefly, while Vera is the same characters favorite weapon. Jayne Cobb is played by Adam Baldwin.
- Mickey, a pilot in Halo ODST, is voiced by Alan Tudyk. Alan Tudyk's character, in Firefly, is also a pilot.
- After a big kill, the character Ditch may say "Dear diary, today I met some aliens and showed them why not to mess with the ODST!", which is a reference to when the character Jayne was digging through one of his shipmate's possessions, in Firefly.
- While not necessarily a deliberate reference, Nathan Fillion's likeness was used for both Gunnery Sergeant Reynolds of Halo 3, and Gunnery Sergeant Edward Buck, in ODST. Reynolds is also the last name of the character he plays, in Firefly.

Comment: This makes me happy on the inside :D

Comment: I believe Reynolds in Firefly was also a Sergeant.